# How to get relative mouse position of screen which is transformed

Tags: position, transform, mouse, win2d

In win2D, Get absolute mouse position is this (from Win2D Sprite Sample)

```
var point = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Position.ToVector2();
```

But, This is Absolute Position,

I make whether mouse is pointing Game Player

So, I made this Code, But It doesn't work.

```
        var rpoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas).Position.ToVector2();



        // 사각형 길을 보여주기  
        if ((rpoint.X > wizardPosition.X - 64) && (rpoint.X < wizardPosition.X + 64) && (rpoint.Y > wizardPosition.Y - 150) && (rpoint.Y < wizardPosition.Y + 42) )
        {
            if (ShowBorder == true) { ShowBorder = false; }

             else if (ShowBorder == false)
                ShowBorder = true; 
        }
```

Does anybody have solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve myself. Anyway. 
The code is this

```
            var rpoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Position.ToVector2();


        // Invert the display transform, to convert pointer positions into simulation rendertarget space.
        Matrix3x2 Mtransform;
        Matrix3x2.Invert(transform, out Mtransform);

        var xpoint = Vector2.Transform(rpoint, Mtransform);

        // 사각형 길을 보여주기  
        if ((xpoint.X > wizardPosition.X - 64) && (xpoint.X < wizardPosition.X + 64) && (xpoint.Y > wizardPosition.Y - 150) && (xpoint.Y < wizardPosition.Y + 42) )
        {
            if (ShowBorder == true) { ShowBorder = false; }

             else if (ShowBorder == false)
                ShowBorder = true; 
        }
```